# Как сделать автономную работу скрипта на Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Перепробовал кучу скриптов, не одна не подошла. При скрытие объекта через `Inspector` и обратного его отображение, перестает работать.
[image: скрытие объекта]

Хотелось бы, чтобы счетчик начал работать и если пользователь перешел на другую `Scenes`, то скрипт останавливал свою работу. Заранее спасибо

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Money : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textScore;
    public int score;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints());
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints()
    {
        while (score < 10000) 
        {
            textScore.text = score.ToString();
            score++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: перечитал вопрос раза 3 и ничерта не понял

Comment: пупсик, я же пытался написать все понятно( @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: скрипт будет переставать работать при переходе на любую другую сцену по дефолту. Наоборот необходимы дополнительные действия что бы он продолжал работать - а если чточнее то необходимо сделать обьект невыгружаемым что бы он перешел с одной сцены в другую и продолжил работать там.

Comment: А та галочка то не скрытие обьекта то отключение обьекта. Оно полностью отключает все скрипты которые висят на обьекте. Корутина на запускается повторно потому что как написано в документации юнити: "Start is called exactly once in the lifetime of the script.". Соответственно что бы запустить корутину заново ее нужно запустить вручную. Или же создать флаг на работу корутины и не вырубать скрипт полностью как это делаешь ты

Comment: То есть оба вопроса заданные в этом вопросе буквально не имеют смысла т.к. вопрос про сцены это и так стандартное поведение и для этого делать ничего не нужно, а вопрос с отключением обьекта это буквально стандартное поведение описанное в документации абсолютно недвузначным текстом буквально в первой строке описания работы метода старт

Comment: А "скрытие обьекта" это отключение скрипта "рендерер". То есть останавливание отрисовки обьекта рендером.

Comment: Спасибо, что объяснил мне, а то я не знал @Andrew_STOP_RU_AGRESSION_IN_UA

Comment: Можешь сказать, как ты учил C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `Start()` - вызывается 1 раз при появлении, и если его отключить и включить снова то метод не сработает.

Чтобы метод срабатывал каждый раз когда его включают есть метод `OnEnable()` - выполняется после активации обьекта, и есть метод `OnDisable()` - который выполняется после деактивации.

Замени `Start()` на `OnEnable()` и это решит твой вопрос

Comment: а какое решение лучше, у тебя или у человека с выше?

Comment: но все же спасибо

Comment: Моё решение не имеет зависимости от других обьектов, поэтому оно удобнее

Answer (score 1):

Пробовал повесить скрипт Money на другой объект? Например, так как на скрине. Если грузить сцену так `SceneManager.LoadScene("YourScene", LoadSceneMode.Single)`, то скрипт работать не будет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: обновил картинку для наглядности. Можно отключать объект Cube неограниченное количество раз, скрипт продолжит работать и обновлять текст

Comment: Все работает, спасибо

Comment: Слушай, а как ты учил C#?

Comment: @ТомасРоджерс Бесплатные и платные курсы по C# и Unity, видео на Youtube, документация C# и Unity с примерами реализаций, ну и профильная литература наконец. Выбирай любое))

Comment: платные курсы где?

Comment: @ТомасРоджерс да поможет тебе гугл)

Comment: слушай можешь дать свою контакты, например телеграмм 